# Is there a way to pass array of arrays or list of lists to sklearn classifiers?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, time-series, classification

I am trying to classify some p300 speller eeg data. So I have a long time series, this time series is divided into epochs (windows of time) of the same length, and each of these epochs have a label. So what I want to do is create a data matrix where the columns are the eeg channels in which we measured the brain activity, and the rows are epochs, in this way I will end up with a matrix where each entry is a time series.
I want to do this because the order of the points within the same epoch should not change, and I want to be able to shuffle the epochs between themselves.

So, after the preprocessing of the data I end up with a pandas data frame [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTXhX.png) where 'condition' is the label, and I arrived here through

```
    df = df.groupby(["epoch", "condition"], as_index = False).agg(
        Fz = ("Fz", pd.Series.to_list),
        C3 = ("C3", pd.Series.to_list),
        Cz = ("Cz", pd.Series.to_list),
        C4 = ("C4", pd.Series.to_list),
        Pz = ("Pz", pd.Series.to_list),
        PO7 = ("PO7", pd.Series.to_list),
        Oz = ("Oz", pd.Series.to_list),
        PO8 = ("PO8", pd.Series.to_list),
    )
```

Then I tried to convert it to an array of arrays in order to pass the data to the classifier for training:

```
    unicorn_channels = ["Fz", "C3", "Cz", "C4", "Pz", "PO7", "Oz", "PO8"]
    pot = df[unicorn_channels].to_numpy()

    for i in range(pot.shape[0]):
      for j in range(pot.shape[1]):
        pot[i,j] = np.array(pot[i,j])

    X = pot
    y = df.condition.to_numpy()
```

So, at this point X is an array of arrays of shape (1200,8), 1200 epochs and 8 channels, and y is (1200,). And, to me it seems all is going right.

Then I pass it to train_test_split to divide in train and test set, and I pass the train set to the classifier, in this case logistic regression, but it gives me the following error:

```
   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
   TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

   The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

   ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
   <timed exec> in <module>

   /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1194             _dtype = [np.float64, np.float32]
   1195 
-> 1196         X, y = self._validate_data(
   1197             X,
   1198             y,

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py in _asarray_with_order(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    183     if xp.__name__ in {"numpy", "numpy.array_api"}:
    184         # Use NumPy API to support order
--> 185         array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    186         return xp.asarray(array, copy=copy)
    187     else:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I tried to do the same passages with list of lists but it gives me a similar error. It appears that the problem is that it is a nested matrix but I hope it is possible to this in some way. Otherwise I could put a single epoch on an entire row, with this the result will be a matrix with shape (1200, 2808), where 2808 = 351 * 8, 351 time points for each epoch and 8 channels, but I am afraid that the algorithm will shuffle through the features and hence through the datapoints, which should not happen.

I hope everything is clear :)

Comment: Question is fine but please add tags for specific programming language/libraries used (e.g. python, PyTorch, etc.)

Comment: Done, sorry, this is my first post

Comment: Functionally, this is a 3 dimensional array. Sklearn normally only works on 2 dimensional arrays, with the first dimension representing which training example it is, and the second dimension representing which feature it is. I don't think you can use sklearn to solve this problem - I think you really want a recurrent neural network. Here's an example of how to do that with keras: https://medium.com/geekculture/predicting-emotions-using-eeg-data-with-recurrent-neural-networks-8acf384896f5